# Is there anyway to access and write data to the internal storage or System Storage from PC?

Tags: internal-storage

I tried to detect my Android storage in Windows. But Windows only detect one storage device, which is my external storage (when activated). How do I actually activate or share the internal storage, so that I could gain access the internal storage and write data onto it?

**Final Objective:**

Write binary data from PC into both internal and external storage.

**Note:**

For External: I found several ways of doing it. One is to Remove the external memory and plug it into the *PC card reader* and start writing. or we could *share the storage media*.

For Internal: I couldn't even detect the storage from the device nor I don't know how to remove the memory. Should it be while the power is off or on to be able to detect the internal memory from PC? Should I have a root access to the phone before able to do it? (I tried rooting the phone, but no luck)

Comment: What device do you have?  Are you talking about an internal "SD card" like the Galaxy S devices have or about the main (system) storage?  The latter just isn't made available to the PC.

Comment: I'm using Samsung Galaxy Gio. I didn't know that there's two storage. Yes, if possible I prefer both, because my objective is to write data to all area of the storage available.

Answer (score 1):

There are many storage locations in an Android device (specially in Samsung Galaxy - series)..

Storage Locations which don't require root access:

1. **External SD:** If your device supports removable MicroSD card, its mounted on `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd` (also hard linked at `/sdcard/external_sd`).
2. **Internal SD** (also labeled as USB Storage)**:** This is mounted at `/mnt/sdcard` (also hard linked at `/sdcard`).

You can [access File System of device over Wi-Fi](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20693/3303). To reach storage locations, just follow the paths. Here, you can write anything without problem, but there may be problem deleting files/directories here due to limited FTP permissions (follow last part of answer to remove this limitation). If you access file systems using USB connection, there shouldn't be any permission problem.

---

Storage Locations which require root access:

3. **System Storage:** Its protected storage of system reserved for apps. e.g. `/data` partition.
4. **ROM:** Its the storage where firmware files can be located. e.g. `/system` partition.

To write here, you do need root access. If your device isn't rooted, you are out of luck. If you are rooted, you can use [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) or [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) to write anything here. Note: You need to mount some partitions with R/W access to write. e.g. `/data` partition is already mounted with R/W access, but `/system` and `/dbdata` partitions are mounted with R/O access.

**Accessing them on PC** is somewhat tricky: Use [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) to mount the partition with R/W access permanently (if its not). Install a native linux FTP server & execute it under root user. Make sure to configure FTP server for accessing the location you want to access. Done! You can now access this location over wi-fi using any FTP client.

---

**Update:**
Its not a concern for questioner, but its worth mentioning: When internal SD is not present, removable MicroSD card might be mounted on `/mnt/sdcard` (also hard linked at `/sdcard`). And, all these mount points are decided by manufacturers, firmwares and may be different. So, its always better to check with `mount` command in Terminal Emulator.

Comment: Note that not all phones have both (1) and (2), some may only have one or the other.

Comment: @GAThrawn That's true, but Galaxy - series always include (2). When it comes to (1), I am not sure about his Galaxy Gio.. That's why I put `if your device supports..`.

Comment: Wow, what a great answer.. (3) is what I am looking for. Thank you very much. I gonna try it out :-)