# Why is CyanogenMod zip not being found when I try to install it?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom, rom-flashing

In order to help fix [my problems with USB connectivity](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22417/5892), it was suggested to me that I upgrade my kernel and ROM. I upgraded the [kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1555259) fine, it seems, but for some reason upgrading the ROM, which is [CyanogenMod](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?device=galaxys2&type=nightly), keeps failing.

I have tried both ways of upgrading, via [recovery](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II:_Full_Update_Guide#Method_via_Recovery) and via [the ROM manager](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II:_Full_Update_Guide#Method_via_ROM_Manager) (for which I purchased the full version). However both fail the exact same way, which is that I get an error message in the recovery interface that says the zip file for the ROM is "not found", despite the fact that the location it says it can't find the file is exactly where the file should be.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: zip install fail]

It says there is a log in `/sdcard/clockworkmod/` directory, but when I look at that directoty, all that I see is a file called `recovery-update.zip`. There are no log files that I can see anywhere.

I have re-downloaded the zip a couple times to be sure it is not a corrupt file or anything, so I think the file is okay.

How do I get the zip to be found so that it can be installed?

Comment: Try renaming the file to `update.zip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to completely wipe all system data before flashing the ROM. Once I did that, the file was found as normal.