# Why can I not access the cyanogenmod zip on my sd card?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s, unbricking

All right, I have fouled up my Galaxy S while trying to install Cyanogenmod after rooting with Odin.

I now have the clockworkMod Recovery 2.5.1.0 and I am trying to select the cyanogen Update .zip from my SD card. Neither option *Apply sdcard:update.zip* and *install zip from sdcard* work

*Apply sdcard:update.zip* simply yield this message:

> E: Can't open /mnt/sdcard/update.zip. No such file or directory. Installation aborted.
>   Mind that I have already renamed the Cyanogen file to update.zip

*install zip from sdcard* does not show the sd directory. The Update.zip is nowhere to be found.

Steps taken so far:

- I have already wiped all the caches (Dalvik and otherwise) and reset.
- This guy's solution did not help either: [Why is CyanogenMod zip not being found when I try to install it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23380/why-is-cyanogenmod-zip-not-being-found-when-i-try-to-install-it)
- I wanted to copy the zip directly to the internal storage ([according to this tutorial](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S:_Full_Update_Guide)), but I don't have access to it anymore. When I connect the phone to my computer, it is does not pop up as an external drive.

Other possibly relevant information:

- After the root, there was a boot loop, which I ignored.
- Shoot me, but there is no backup
- **Edit**: My firmware was XWJW5, Version 2.3.6

Question:

- Is there any way I can still access the cyanogenmod file - or any other file - on my SD card?
- Can my Galaxy S be saved somehow?
- Among the myriad of options to root your device out there, which one could help me?

Comment: After doing the Heimdall-Manoever which restored my OS, I transferred cyanogen to the internal memory. However, Cyanogen does not play well with my device and I've abandoned it.

Comment: Didn't play well with my SGS either, too bad.  Hopefully you've picked up some skills from the process though :)

Comment: @MatthewRead oh yes, I did! Wasted 5-6 hours, though, and shortened my life span by 5-6 years. Can start earning points here, now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wanted to copy the zip directly to the internal storage

You can't just want to, you *have to*.  ClockworkMod does not mount the external SD card, you have to put it on the internal SD storage (often called the internal SD card and separate from the main system storage).

If you can't access the internal SD then you'll need to flash an Odin-packed ROM (with Odin of course) to fix your device.  Ideally you should flash the same version of stock that originally came with it.  See [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/1465) if needed :)

Comment: @user99572isfine Good luck! :)

Comment: @matthew_read Odin does recognize my phone anymore. Trying Heimdall now. other suggestions?

Comment: @user99572isfine Can you provide more detail?  Make sure you're in Download mode before using Odin or Heimdall.

Comment: I am in download mode and see the yellow triangle. The drivers are installed from before, just it does not turn yellow. Seems like I should rephrase my question.

Comment: @matthew_read I am stuck waiting for the Heimdall package to download. Bloody filehosters. Will continue tomorrow.

Answer (score 10):

You most probably have an *unpartitioned* sdcard, clockworkmod however assumes that is partitioned and wants to mount the first partition (/dev/block/mmcblk0p1).

You can fix this by repartitioning your sdcard so that it has a mountable fat-formatted first volume and then retry.

If you don't mind using the commandline, boot to recovery and connect via `adb shell` to it, then mount your sdcard manually: `mount /dev/block/mmcblk0 /sdcard` and retry.

Technical explanation:

`cat /proc/partitions` lists:

**/dev/block/mmcblk0** is your FAT formatted volume (no more partitions at all)

should be:
**/dev/block/mmcblk0** (whole device)
**/dev/block/mmcblk0p1** (1st partition, FAT formatted)
**/dev/block/mmcblk0p2** (sd-ext partition, only for those that use SD2ext and such)

Comment: I think since partitioning will erase all the data in the card, I'll just work from my internal sd. Thanks btw!

Comment: yes. repartitioning needs a backup first or all data is lost afterwards. I also have this issue and solve it by manually mounting it via adb each time i update out of laziness

Comment: Just helped me recover 500+ photos and videos from an inaccesible SD card partition. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

download this link "PDA_BCK_CF-root_universal_beta14fix" and install using odin selecting pda which will root your device and later you will find what you want i mean the "install zip from sd card" i tried it and it works for me.