# Can't mount sdcard from Recovery Mode/Clockworkmod

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing, external-sd, recovery-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I not access the cyanogenmod zip on my sd card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23742/why-can-i-not-access-the-cyanogenmod-zip-on-my-sd-card)

I'm trying to install a custom ROM on my rooted Galaxy S2, I've been following this guide:
http://www.theandroidsoul.com/android-4-0-4-for-galaxy-s2-i9100-flash-the-f1-galaxynexus-rom/

I've placed the rom inside an external sdcard, entered Recovery mode (clockworkmod CMW-based Recovery) and clicked "install zip from sdcard" then "choose zip from sdcard", after that the console presented me with an error "E:Can't mount /sdcard/".

The sdcard works fine and I'm able to read/write from/to it without any issues.